# Visual Studio 2008 Very Slow Debugging Managed to Unmanaged Transition (only one machine though)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, settings, unmanaged

I have some C# code which passed a delegate as a callback to an unmanaged method via a P/Invoke function call in a NUnit test.

The code works great and passes all tests in both Relase and Debug modes.  And it runs fast on one machine whether running under the Debugger or not.

But after setting up a nearly identical development environment on another PC for a new developer starting soon, it runs fast in Release and Debug configuration. But horribly slow when the Debugger is attached.

Note that I have seen a type of slowness with "debug unmanaged code" enabled on the Project. I have disabled that, recompiled and it doesn't matter with or w/o. I tried it both ways several times.

Also, there aren't any break points or watch variables set.

As an aside, this unit test actually calls the unmanaged method in a loop 1 million times which returns after incrementing a counter. It's extremely simple code that was only testing the performance of making unmanaged calls across AppDomains.

Please remember that this is identical code from git commit that only runs slow when under the debugger on one of the machines. No code modifications are different between them so it seems conclusively this isn't a "code" issue but rather a setting in Visual Studio somewhere related to unmanaged vs. managed debugging, I will wildly guss.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.  If you really think seeing the code will help. I'll post the unit C# test and the cpp file too.

Edit: I narrowed down that this slowness in the debugger only happens for the unmanaged code that calls into a different AppDomain. So in these performance tests there is the primary and another, secondary AppDomain. Managed to Unmanaged calls are tested to callback from the primary domain to itself. Those are fast! But those that callback across from unmanaged into the other AppDomain are very, very slow.  This means from 20 million per second down to only 4 or 5 thousand per second.

Note that the method being called to test is void callback()--so not arguments or return value.  In other words, there's nothing to marshall.

Edit: I was jiggerng with different settings and now my development box is SLOW too.  I was sure it was the "Just My Code" setting that saw was off for the faster machine so enabled it to try that out. But now, even after disabling it again, it's still slow. So not sure if this is the cause or not.

Comment: stab in the dark: local versus roaming user profile?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that's over my head, it seems. What is a "roaming user profile"?  And why will it only affect code that makes an unmanaged transition?  Oh, perhaps the the post very clear about the fact that all of the code performance tests which only involve C# w/o unmanaged, P/Invoke calls work fine under the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Check if symbol files settings are the same on both machines. Loading all symbols for native code may take very long time (Tools -> Options ->Debugging -> Symbols).

Comment: My symbols files on both computers are empty. The field is blank. Any other ideas?